# How to set fields of an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `SVGElement`. It has three private fields: `String fillColor`, `String strokeColor`, `String strokeWidth.`

I have another class `SVGCircleElement` which implements `SVGElement`, `SVGCircle` has its own fields `radius`, `centerX`, and `centerY`.

I am testing out the `SVGCircleElement`. I have the following code:

```
SVGCircleElement circle = new SVGCircleElement();
circle.setCx(40);
circle.setCy(40);
circle.setRadius(50);
```

How do I set the fields `fillColor`, `strokeColor`, and `strokeWidth`?

Comment: Make sure `SVGElement` class has proper setter methods for the private fields.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same way you set fields of any other class. The fact that the class the fields are defined on is abstract has zero bearing on how you set the fields.

In your specific case, do `circle.setFillColor("red");` etc, and make sure that either `SVGElement` or `SVGCircleElement` provides those public setter methods.